# Unable to run ignite example

Tags: ignite

I am trying to run ignite basic example and it is failing with spark TaskNotSerializable error. Could you please help me out.?

```
val ignite = Ignition.start("/usr/local/ignite/config/example-ignite.xml");
val cfg = ignite.configuration() 
val ic = new IgniteContext[Integer, Integer](sc, () => cfg)
Ignition.setClientMode(true); 

val sharedRdd = ic.fromCache("example")
val x = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10000, 10).map(i => (new Integer(i), new Integer(i)))
sharedRdd.savePairs(x)
```

Comment: What version of Ignite & Spark do you use on your side? Also please add the full stack trace you see while executing the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is not implements as Serializable then also above exception occurs due to spark. To avoid this exception make your class Serializable (implements Serializable)